# Do receiving addresses expire on Multibit?

Tags: blockchain, address, multibit, coinbase.com, receiving

Okay so I have tried Resetting Blockchain and Transactions plenty of times. The only thing is I used an old receiving address that I used about 2 months ago. Do these addresses expire? Can they only be used once? I don't know. I'm not too good at this. Here is my Wallet: http://puu.sh/8CBpT.png Here is the blockchain of my receiving address: https://blockchain.info/address/12EFht1oW3h2ybNYP2NrJKF26oPicFs8mM Is there any way to retrieve my bitcoin? Do you guys have any answers? I have looked everywhere on google and I have gotten nowhere.

Comment: That's weird. It is accepted, your wallet contains ~0.20 BTC but it doesn't show up in Multibit, right? Normally a reset would yield the proper result. Is multibit (and your computer) connected to the internet? Is Multibit updated? I guess it is, but it *should* work.

Comment: Im going to try to back it up and use a different wallet software. Hopefully that works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

But to answer the question: addresses do NOT expire. Not in Multibit, not in cold storage, not online (unless the site retired and you do not have an offline private key or wallet), nor any other wallet software. They can be used unlimited amount of times, so that's not the problem either. The problem your face is probably in Multibit. You can try to backup the `.wallet` or `.key`, and import it in another wallet software, or delete/reinstall Multibit.